# Edit SSIS package where table consists of 10million rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

i am working on a SSIS Package where i will transfer data from oracle DB to SQL DB.
MY SSIS will transfer 
oracle Students

```
name  year gpa  completed
a     2013 3   2015
b     2013 4   2016
SQL Students

name  year gpa 
a     2013 3   
b     2013 4
```

Now i need to add  completed column to sql table.what is the best approach 
1)do i need to create new table?
2)alter table and add column?
Note :Oracle table consists of million rows?

Answer (score 0):

you have to do alter table and add that column.